# how can i transform my josn_encode data in array into google bar chart?

Tags: php, arrays, json, charts, google-visualization

This is my `json_encoded` data

```
$encoded_data = json_encode($data);

echo $encoded_data;

[{"cols":"2017-09-02 11:01:55","rows":"1186.55"},{"cols":"2017-09-03 11:31:35","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 15:22:38","rows":"90000.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 16:39:16","rows":"90000.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 16:40:09","rows":"630.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 17:25:26","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 17:54:50","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 09:28:57","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:20:16","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:22:28","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:27:52","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:34:00","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:39:46","rows":"91575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:40:48","rows":"91311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:47:34","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:50:53","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:51:18","rows":"1575.00"}]

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('visualization', '1',  {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.

        var jsonData = <?php echo $encoded_data;  ?>

         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);




        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'sales chart',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>



    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

It gives me an error the table has no columns.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on the javascript side here
"var jsonData = <?php echo $encoded_data;  ?> ;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the json is not in the correct format to create the data table directly,
see the structure of the JavaScript literal object [described here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)...

if you don't want to change the format, then it can be transformed using javascript

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = [{"cols":"2017-09-02 11:01:55","rows":"1186.55"},{"cols":"2017-09-03 11:31:35","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 15:22:38","rows":"90000.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 16:39:16","rows":"90000.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 16:40:09","rows":"630.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 17:25:26","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-06 17:54:50","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 09:28:57","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:20:16","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:22:28","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:27:52","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:34:00","rows":"1311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:39:46","rows":"91575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:40:48","rows":"91311.45"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:47:34","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:50:53","rows":"1575.00"},{"cols":"2017-09-07 10:51:18","rows":"1575.00"}];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
    data.addRow([
      row.cols,
      parseFloat(row.rows)
    ]);
  });

  var options = {
    title: 'sales chart',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    chartArea: {
      left: 140
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```